# Application won't bind to service

Tags: android, service, bind

I have an application A that has to bind to a service that is in another package. I have put a custom intent filter in order to make it work. Sadly the application wont bind. The log says that it can't find the service.

Application A is in the package "com.example.app_a"
The service is in another package "com.example.app_talker_service"

So I just can't refer to the service with the xxx.class solution, so my guess was to use an intent filter in the manifest file of the service's package.

Application A, on the other hand, will need to do a bind to the service to make it start (if it hasn't already started) and that later it will communicate with it though the use of broadcast receivers. I did some experimentation and I noticed that the broadcasts work fine, but what is wrond is that for some reason, the application A can't seem to find my service during the binding....

Here is the code for application A which binds in onStart():

```
    @Override
protected void onStart() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();

    //Bind to service
    getApplicationContext().bindService(new Intent("com.example.talker_service.SERVICE"), mConnection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);


}
    private boolean mIsBound = false;

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection()
{

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mIsBound = true;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CONNECTED TO SERVICE!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.setAction("com.example.talker_service.SERVICE");
         intent.putExtra("REQUEST", "REGISTER APP");

         intent.putExtra("FILTER", "com.example.app_a");
         intent.putExtra("NAME", "Applicazione A");

         String[] components = {"NUMBER_SENT","CHANGE_TEXT_COLOR","CHANGE_TEXTVIEW_SIZE"};
         intent.putExtra("COMPONENTS", components);

         MainActivityA.this.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mIsBound = false;
    }

};
```

Here instead is the cmanifest for the service which I called Talker_service:

```
    en<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app_talker_service"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <service
            android:name=".Talker_Service"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.example.talker_service.SERVICE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name=".ConnectionManagerActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_connection_manager" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I don't undertsand why it doesn't bind.. I put the intent filter, am I missing something? Ah, and the logs says this:

> 12-03 22:45:13.786: W/ContextImpl(26076): Implicit intents with startService are 
>   not safe: Intent {
>   act=com.example.talker_service.SERVICE }
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService:517
>   com.example.app_a.MainActivityA.onStart:81
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart:1171 
>       12-03 22:45:13.786: W/ActivityManager(764): Unable to start service Intent { >act=com.example.talker_service.SERVICE } U=0: not
>   found

This instead is the manifest file for application A

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app_a"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" ></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivityA"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why using intent filters is not working (it says that it can't find it) but by using the following code I was able to make my application connect to the remote service:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClassName("com.example.app_talker_service", "com.example.app_talker_service.Talker_Service");
    bindService(i, conn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

so using the seClassName method and providing the name of the pacake and that full path of the service, I was able to make it work. I am not sure if this falls in the realm of "best practice" for this type of problem, but for my it worked. Any solution is better than no solution. I found this solution thants to this link:

[Remote Service Tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/remote_service_tutorial-t8127.html)

Comment: This link provided is very old, I think that now the signature of method call setClass is changed.